# Salesforce picklist hide none value

Tags: picklist

I'am creating a standard picklist field with values "None" and "Yes" but when I see on the detail page while creating a record I see two none values in the picklist , one defined by me and other coming as by default .

How can I remove the standard None picklist value?
Also , I want to make the "None" defined by me as the default picklist value selected while creating the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the default standard "None" value remove from the picklist their are two things required :-

1. Make the field required from page layout.
2. Go to replace in the picklist field and replace the standard "None"
   value from your any value in the picklist . Since the picklist is a
   set and no duplicate values can be present , so the "None" value
   will get removed from the picklist.
3. In case you're using Record Types. Selecting another value than --None-- as the default value for that picklist in the record type.

Answer (score 6):

Just go to the Picklist definition on the custom object and select Reorder and it allows you to set a Default value.

Build>Create>Objects>My Object>Custom Fields

Then on the page layout make the picklist required so it will not permit a value of the Salesforce default 'none'.

Build>Create>Objects>My Object>Page Layouts

This will mean that the standard Salesforce 'none' option on the picklist in the detail page is hidden.

Comment: thanks @Dave but this did not work . I am still seeing the default "--None--" value in the picklist.

Comment: @JiteshGoel, you will also need to make field mandatory on page layout. Just editing this into the answer